# PHP Script Not Checking Multiple Lines in .txt file

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple login script that will check the inputted username and password against a .txt file.  The problem I have found is that my script only checks the FIRST LINE of my .txt file. That is, if the first line of the .txt file reads "test|test123" and I enter "test" as the username and "test123" as the password, everything works.  However, when I do the same with the rest of my lines, it returns the "invalid password or username" statement.  I believe my script is not checking other lines in my .txt file against the inputted username and password?  How can this be fixed?

```
<?php

$check = 0;
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$username = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
$username = strtolower($username);
$password = htmlentities($_POST['apw']);
$filename = getcwd() . "/atextfile.txt";
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
{
    list($name, $pw) = explode('|', $line);
    if($name == $username && $pw == $password)
$check++;
break;  
 }
if ($check == 1){
header("location: index.php");

}

else{
printf("Your username or password are invalid. Please try again.");

}

}

?>

<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p>
Username:<br />
<input type = "text" id="name" name="name" size="20" maxlength="40" />
</p>

<p>
Password:<br />
<input type = "password" id="apw" name="apw" size="20" maxlength="40" />
</p>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name ="submit" name ="submit" value="Log in" />

<p>
<a href="register.php">Register</a></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
{
    list($name, $pw) = explode('|', $line);
    if($name == $username && $pw == $password)
    $check++;
    break;  
}
```

It should be

```
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
{
    list($name, $pw) = explode('|', $line);
    if($name == $username && $pw == $password)
    {
        $check++;
        break;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the break statement inside  {} block in the if instruction. At this moment it's always breaking after first line

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dan. Just to make it more clear.. i have added the corrected code below.

```
foreach($lines as $key => $line)       
{
    list($name, $pw) = explode('|', $line);   
    if($name == $username && $pw == $password) 

      {                 
             $check++;
             break;  
      }
 }
```